# Different ways to grasp the general definition of polarization

Tags: electric-fields, tensor-calculus, polarization

I would like to grasp the definition of polarization in general case (not only for linear mode):

$$\vec{P}=\epsilon_{0}\chi \vec{E}$$

In linear regime, $\chi$ can be assimilated to a $3\times3$ matrix such as :

\begin{align}
P_{x} &= \epsilon_{0}\chi_{xx}E_{x}+\epsilon_{0}\chi_{xy}E_{y}+\epsilon_{0}\chi_{xz}E_{z}\\
P_{y} &= \epsilon_{0}\chi_{yx}E_{x}+\epsilon_{0}\chi_{yy}E_{y}+\epsilon_{0}\chi_{yz}E_{z}\\
P_{z} &= \epsilon_{0}\chi_{zx}E_{x}+\epsilon_{0}\chi_{zy}E_{y}+\epsilon_{0}\chi_{zz}E_{z}
\end{align}
What's the best approach to understand these relations? Should one consider $\chi$ as a linear map or rather as a bilinear form (a (2,0) tensor)?

At first sight, I would say that $\chi$ has be considered as a linear operator, so as a matrix but I am not sure.

Moreover, in non-linear mode, one says on [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility#Nonlinear_susceptibility) that polarization $\vec{P}$ depends on square and even more $E^2$ terms of electric fields; a Taylor expansion gives :

$$P=P_{0}+\epsilon_{0}\chi^{(1)}E+\epsilon_{0}\chi^{(2)}E^2+\epsilon_{0}\chi^{(3)}E^3 +...\quad (1)$$

It is also said that the nonlinear regime implies the using of tensor with rank > 2: How can I define the general expression of $P$ above from a matricial point of view ? i.e I don't know how to make appear the powered terms $E^{n}$ of electric field with tensors convention. It seems that in linear mode, we have the linear map $\chi$ but it only implies the 3 components $E_{x},E_{y},E_{z}$, not for example the components $E_{x}^2,E_{y}^2,E_{z}^2$ or even $E_{x}^3,E_{y}^3,E_{z}^3$.

I know that a tensor is a matrix associated to a bilinear form but I can't visualize and make the link with nonlinear components: how can I translate the equation (1) and electric susceptibility with tensors concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regards your first question,

> Should one consider $\chi$ as a linear map or rather as a bilinear form (a (2,0) tensor)?

the answer is that it doesn't matter: any linear map $A$ can be used to construct a bilinear form $w(x,y) = \langle x, Ay\rangle$ and vice versa, so that there is an [isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) (known in physics as just raising and lowering indices) that connects the two pictures, and you can work in whichever is most comfortable without fear of losing out on the descriptive power of your theory.

In your specific case, though, the linear susceptibility is generally best thought of as a linear operator, which takes applied electric fields $\vec E$ and returns the electric polarization $\vec P = \epsilon_0 \chi \vec E$ which they produce; for a linear material this polarization depends linearly on $\vec E$ so the map is a linear operator.

(But, that said, the bilinear form is also very useful ─ it is just the energy $W = \frac12 \vec E \cdot \vec P = \frac12 \langle \vec E, \epsilon_0 \chi \vec E\rangle$ required to produce the polarization.)

---

As for the higher-order terms, you are completely correct: they must be described by tensors of a rank higher than two, which, more specifically, are best thought of as instantiating multi-linear maps 
$$
\overbrace{\mathbb R^3 \times \cdots \times \mathbb R^3}^{n} \to \mathbb R^3,
$$
where $n$ is the order of the process. Generally, in these maps the entries are just taken over a single repeated entry, the electric field, but depending on the process you're describing (say, second-harmonic generation vs sum- or difference-frequency generation) then the different entries can be taken as the different waves that contribute to the process.

In more concrete terms, though, the quadratic polarization goes as
$$
P^{(2)}_i = \epsilon_0 \chi^{(2)}_{ijk} E_j E_k,
$$
the cubic term reads
$$
P^{(3)}_i = \epsilon_0 \chi^{(3)}_{ijkl} E_j E_k E_l,
$$
and so on.

Comment: -@Emilio Pisanty. Thanks, your answer is clear, I understand better the non-linear terms